# how to execute this "MySQL" query for all values that are in my column "horse" ... here this query execture 1 value in my column "horse"

Tags: mysql, sql, select, average, window-functions

how to execute a "MySQL" query for all
values that are in my column ?

Here is my table

```
Table A
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          id          |        CL           |     horse        |    
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|           1          |        1er          |     C.Ferland    |
|           2          |        5e           |     Abrivard     |
|           3          |        3e           |     P. Hawas     |
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want the output to be:

```
+------------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+
|    horse   | Top_1  | Top_2_3 | TOP_4_5 | TOP_total |
+------------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+
| C. Ferland | 0.1757 |  0.2788 |  0.1892 |    0.6436 |
|  Abrivard  | 0.0394 |  0.1231 |  0.1575 |    0.3199 |
| P. Hawas   | 0.0461 |  0.1263 |  0.1092 |    0.2816 |
+------------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Currently, I'm running this query for a value in my horse column.
And that works very well.

```
SELECT horse,
sum(case when `cl` = '1er' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as Top_1, 
sum(case when `cl` BETWEEN 2 AND 3 then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as Top_2_3,
sum(case when `cl` BETWEEN 4 AND 5 then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as TOP_4_5,
sum(case when `cl` BETWEEN 1 AND 5 then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as TOP_total
FROM p_mu.cachedate
WHERE horse ="C.Ferland";
```

How to adapt this query for all the values in my "horse" column.
Thank you for your help..

Comment: Luckily your query is already using aggregating functions, so you can just replace `where horse = '...'` with `group by horse`

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, but your desired results show that you want to compute the average over the *whole dataset*, not only over the rows of the group. Window functions come handy for this:

```
select
    horse,
    sum(cl = 1)      / count(*) over() top_1,
    sum(cl in (2,3)) / count(*) over() top_2_3,
    sum(cl in (4,5)) / count(*) over() top_4_5,
    sum(cl <= 5)     / count(*) over() top_1_5
from p_mu.cachedate
group by horse
```

If you want to filter on a given horse, you need a derived table:

```
select *
from (
    select
        horse,
        sum(cl = 1)      / count(*) over() top_1,
        sum(cl in (2,3)) / count(*) over() top_2_3,
        sum(cl in (4,5)) / count(*) over() top_4_5,
        sum(cl <= 5)     / count(*) over() top_1_5
    from p_mu.cachedate
    group by horse
) t
where horse = 'C.Ferland'
```

---

This works in MySQL 8.0 only. In earlier versions, you can use a subquery instead:

```
select
    horse,
    sum(cl = 1)      / x.cnt top_1,
    sum(cl in (2,3)) / x.cnt top_2_3,
    sum(cl in (4,5)) / x.cnt top_4_5,
    sum(cl <= 5)     / x.cnt top_1_5
from p_mu.cachedate
inner join (select count(*) cnt from p_mu.cachedate) x
group by horse
```

Comment: Great, it works, that's what I wanted exactly; thank you